# Full Continuous integration pipieline as a service

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am building the [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) for a small startup at Amazon EC2. At the current stage, the architecture is based on a bunch of RESTful services written in Python, connecting to a  few databases.

I would like to set up a classic CI-CD pipeline with:

Code commits → 
Unit tests → 
Deployment on dev environment →
Functional and integration tests → 
Deployment in production → 
Validation tests →
Revert if necessary.

This image ([credit](http://www.centrumsystems.com.au/2011/02/build-pipeline-hudson-jenkins-plugin-1-0-0-released/)) illustrates the general idea:

[image]

This can be set using a dedicated [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)/Hudson machine on EC2. The alternative is using web applications like [drone.io](https://drone.io/) and [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/). These webapps can check out code, run  tests and deploy. However, the ones I have inspected lack the ability to have a full CI-CD pipeline with dependencies.

Are there any CI-CD web application that feature full pipeline with build dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a founder of CircleCI, and obviously I keep an eye on the landscape. Currently, (early 2014) Jenkins is your only option for a multi-stage CI/CD pipeline like this.

Obviously, this is a problem that [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) will solve in the future!

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. And feel free to update your answer whenever you support full pipelines. I'll stay tuned!